# Facebook Graph API limit for apprequests edge

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

Trying to get all the apprequests for a certain user, using the v2.2 open graph call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/<facebookID>/apprequests?access_token=<accessToken>&format=json&limit=500&method=get
```

Can't find in Facebook's documentation what's the upper bound for "limit", and I don't have that many apprequests to test that. I'm looking for the actual value at which Facebook caps the requests and pagination is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The upper number for the `limit` parameter differs per endpoint. This is because of performance differences per endpoint.

This is documented in the section about traversing the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#paging:

> limit : This is the number of individual objects that are returned in
>   each page. Note that this is an upper limit, if there are not enough
>   remaining objects in the list of data, then less than this number will
>   be returned. Some edges have an upper maximum on the limit value, for
>   performance reasons. We will return the correct pagination links if
>   that happens.

This means that you can request any number and that will be capped by Facebook's maximum for that edge.

Comment: My question exactly, what is the upper limit for apprequests endpoint?

Comment: As I already answered; it differs per endpoint and is not documented. Why do you want the exact number?

Comment: just as a way to estimate, as moving from FQL to Graph API changed the way we work with apprequests. Thanks.